# Coulomb torsion balance : force or torque

Tags: forces, experimental-physics, differential-geometry, torque, coulombs-law

The following links talk about the torsion balance equation of Coulomb.

$$F_{\tau} = w \dfrac{\alpha\ D^4}{l}$$

Due to a wide variety of names for the $LHS$ of equation, **I am totally confused whether it is referring to force $(F=ma)$ or torque $(\tau=|\vec{F} \times \vec{r}|)$**.

**Please help me clarify**.

1. [AA Martinez : page 519](http://www.scienzadellecostruzioni.co.uk/Documenti/Replication%20of%20Coulomb%E2%80%99s%20Torsion%20Balance.pdf)
2. [Elay Shech & Eric Hatleback page 9](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11048/1/The_Material_Intricacies_of_Coulomb%27s_1785_Electric_Torsion_Balance_Experiment_%28EV%29.pdf)
3. [Website](https://www.npl.washington.edu/eotwash/torsion-balances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first reference defines the symbols and makes it clear that the formula refers to the twisting of a wire.  Since no lever arm is given, the F must symbolize a torque.

Comment: $F_\tau=|\vec{F}| |\vec{r}| \sin(F,r)$. In order to find $|\vec{F}|$, how shall we know the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{r}$?

Comment: If we know $F_\tau$ and $|\vec{r}|$ in advance

Comment: A rose by any other name.  The formula gives a torque.